# How to Build transaction XDR before signing it and then later add the signature to the XDr

Tags: stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory

I'm trying to build an XDR utilizing txnbuild, a Stellar SDK in Go. I've tried some examples given way back in 2018 but most of the methods are deprecated. For example : [What is the correct way to unmarshal an encoded transaction for signing](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2689/what-is-the-correct-way-to-unmarshal-an-encoded-transaction-for-signing)
How to use the current methods and build an XDR with no sign and then later unmarshall the XDR and add a sign?

Note : This could be easily done on Stellar laboratory, so I assume there should be way on code level too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer using the txnbuild and xdr SDKs for Go. https://medium.com/@keleighberenger/signing-pre-built-xdrs-using-the-stellar-sdks-for-golang-9b7ec6065ff7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).